# Proof sprague-grundy value is 0 if and only if it is losing position

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

So, i take this game theory module this summer, and i encountered this exercise problem, i tried to do this by induction by have terminal position (grundy-value = 0) as base case, but can't figure out the inductive step, can someone help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you assuming the set of positions is finite, or can it be infinite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Call a position "weird" if Sprague-Grundy gives the wrong answer, i.e., either the Sprague-Grundy number is zero and it's not a losing position (for the player to move next), or else the Sprague-Grundy number is positive and it's not a winning position. Prove that **in any weird position there is a move which leads to another weird position.** It follows that, if a weird position exists, then an infinite play from that position is possible. The basic assumptions of the game (an acyclic digraph which is finite or at least "progressively finite") imply that an infinite play is impossible.

Comment: thanks, i got the idea, it's a really nice prove. But i'm having a problem defining whether a game is finite or infinite, can you give me some more hint ? does having no cycle implies finite ?

Comment: It might work better if you told me how games and the S-G function are defined in the course you're taking, instead of me trying to guess and perhaps confusing you with a more general approach than the one you've seen. But I'm going to **guess** that, in your class, a game is a **finite** directed graph without cycles; the nodes of the graph are positions in the game, and a directed edge from one node to another is a possible move. ("Finite" just means that the number of positions in the game is some positive integer $n$.)

Comment: Sprague-Grundy theory also work for games on an **infinite** digraph (infinitely many possible positions), suitably restricted so that endless play is impossible; in some cases (if there are infinitely many possible moves from a position) nonnegative integers won't suffice for the S-G values, you will have to allow "transfinite ordinal numbers" as well. However, I'm guessing your module is not covering such things.

Comment: seems that i misunderstood the definition of finite, finite means there's finite number of position and infinite means there's infinite number of position right ? here's one of the game presented on my class, two players play on 8x8 board, then each player took turn coloring 1x1 or 2x2 square in the board without overlapping existing color, how can i say this game is a finite game ? it is clear that it is finite when i think about it but hard to be written in formal words.

Comment: Of course the number of positions is finite. You have an $8\times8$ board, $64$ squares, each square either uncolored or colored. $2$ possibilities for each square, $64$ squares, so the number of positions is $2^{64}$, a $20$-digit number, between $18$ and $19$ quintillion. Definitely finite.

Comment: got it! thanks for your help